# How do we migrate Application server Broadworks to Network Server Broadworks

Tags: linux

In our lab, we have one Broadworks application server, now we have to change/migrate as a Network server Broadwork.

Please any provide link or info/procedure to change/migrate to Application server to Network server

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall-all (script by BS)  which will remove AS, then install NS on the same machine. But you will new license files.